# VB.Net SQL Stored Procedure cache / Parameter Count Value?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I'm pretty new to Web Development so this (hopefully) may have an easy answer.

Basically, I have a stored procedure that originally took two parameters. I changed it to only require one. Now I send a request from VB.Net to use the procedure with the one parameter required.

> Parameter count does not match Parameter Value count.

So I add the old second parameter back to the request, even though it's not part of the actual stored procedure anymore.

> Procedure or function xw_GetProducts_by_Brand has too many arguments specified.

So I declare the old parameter in SQL again, even though the query doesn't use it. Sending both parameters from VB.Net

> Procedure or function 'xw_GetProducts_by_Brand' expects parameter '@AccountNo', which was not supplied.

So lastly, I leave both parameters (String/nvarchar and Int) declared in SQL but remove the unneeded int from VB.Net, just in case.

> Parameter count does not match Parameter Value count.

So... I have a query that was working fine until I removed the unused int parameter and now it won't work no matter what parameter set up I use. Is there a cache time on stored procedures (either in VB/ASP.Net or SQL Server) that would be screwing up my page?

I don't think the actual query itself is a problem because everything worked until I removed the line `@AccountNo int` from the declarations.

**VB.Net**:

```
Dim data1 As DataTable = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("dbConn"), 
    "xw_GetStockCodesInBrand", brand.Value
    ).Tables(0)

Dim stockString As String = "'"

For Each row As DataRow In data1.Rows
    stockString += row("StockCode") + "','"
Next

Dim stockStringFinal As String = 
stockString.Substring(0, stockString.Length - 2)

Dim dt As DataTable = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("dbConn"), 
    "xw_GetProducts_by_Brand", stockStringFinal
    ).Tables(0)
```

Data one gets the string of stockcode values, they get trimmed by the substring and submitted as a parameter for DT(datatable).

The second `SqlHelper` request is the issue, it doesn't accept an int parameter and won't work without 2 parameters.

**SQL query**:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[xw_GetProducts_by_Brand3] 
    @ProductID nvarchar(max)
AS
    SELECT 
        stock_items.Stockcode, STOCK_GROUPS.XW_URL as stockgroup,
        STOCK_GROUP2S.XW_URL as stockgroup2, 
        STOCK_MAINGROUP.XW_URL as stockmaingroup, 
        stock_items.Stockcode as pID, stock_items.description as pName, 
        stock_web.sales_html as pdescription, 
        stock_web.picture_url as pImage, 
        stock_web.picture_url as pLargeimage, 
        stock_items.sellprice1 as pPrice, 
        stock_items.SELLPRICE1, stock_items.SELLPRICE2, 
        stock_items.SELLPRICE3, stock_items.SELLPRICE4, 
        stock_items.SELLPRICE5, stock_items.SELLPRICE6, 
        stock_items.SELLPRICE7, stock_items.SELLPRICE8, 
        stock_items.SELLPRICE9, stock_items.status as itemtype, 
        stock_items.SELLPRICE10 as pListPrice, 
        stock_items.x_totalstock as pInStock, 
        stock_items.x_webhits as pHits, 
        stock_items.ISACTIVE, stock_items.WEB_SHOW, 
        stock_items.X_WebBlub as X_WebBlurb, 
        stock_items.x_webpromo as X_PROMOPAGE, 
        stock_items.last_updated as lastupdated, 
        stock_items.x_stockleveloverride, 
        isnull(stock_items.Restricted_item,'N') as Restricted_item 
    FROM 
        stock_items 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        STOCK_WEB ON (stock_items.Stockcode = STOCK_WEB.Stockcode) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        STOCK_GROUPS ON (STOCK_GROUPS.GROUPNO = STOCK_ITEMS.STOCKGROUP)  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        STOCK_GROUP2S ON (STOCK_GROUP2S.GROUPNO = STOCK_ITEMS.STOCKGROUP2) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        STOCK_MAINGROUP ON (STOCK_MAINGROUP.GROUPNO = STOCK_GROUPS.XW_MAINGROUP)
    WHERE 
        stock_items.ISACTIVE = 'Y'  
        AND stock_web.picture_url IS NOT NULL 
        AND stock_items.Stockcode IN (@ProductID)
```

**Fix**

I got around this issue by renaming my stored procedure and pretending it's a whole new procedure. If anyone knows the actual cause behind this issue I'd still like to get it fixed.

Comment: Post your actual code vb.net code

Answer (score 0):

Probably when I wiped out the second parameter from your SQL procedure you forgot the "," need to allow the next (and last) parameter. Chekit it out. So, based on your description, the last parameter of your SQL procedure is ending with a "," - and it´s cause an error. Take the comma off.

Comment: I pass a second string, `stockStringFinal` which is the generated string with the last two characters (,') trimmed off the end. I've tested it by outputting that to a label and copy/pasting it into SQL. When I copy/Paste directly into SQL instead of using the parameter it returns all the correct information.

Comment: I believe your problem is related to the last comma. Try to, after generating the string, delete the last two characters (the comma and the ' ) and put the " instead. Something like:  1) string = mid(string, 1, string.length - 2)    2) string = string & chr(34)  << I guess character ".   But, to me, the problem could be related to the SQL Stored Procedure, ending the parameter with a comma (it shouldn´t).

Comment: Already done in VB. If you have another look at my code, you'll see that I trim the extra punctuation off the end of it, creating a second string, which is used as the parameter. The error is somewhere else, as everything works fine when I rename the procedure and call it by it's new name.

Comment: Ops! Sorry Chris, I really didn´t pay the necessary attention. My point is: the Stored Procedure had 2 parameters - so, the first MUST end with a comma and the second, not.  If your simply wiped the first parameter, is usual to forget the comma at the end of the first one and it can cause an error. Should´t it be the root of the problem?

Comment: Try to change from "Substring" function to "MID" function (remember: the first position is not 0 but 1). It can be an internal problem of VB.

Comment: If you're referring to the declarations in SQL, I removed the second parameter (an integer) leaving just a string (nvarchar(MAX) - to allow for potentially large searches). Declared like this, `ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[xw_GetProducts_by_Brand3] 
@ProductID nvarchar(max)
AS`

Comment: Are you defining the STored Procedure in the MS-SQL? I´m not used with that notation you´re using.

Comment: The company I work for uses Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I guess that's MS-SQL? I'm pretty new at this. Yeah, Stored Procedure is being defined and saved using Server Studio. Also, VB6 (and below) had a weird thing giong with 0 or 1 being first postion but VB.Net (being a .Net language) 0 is first position.

Comment: I believe your problem IS in the Stored Procedure and, viewing your line, the "AS" at the end is wrong.  Using the SQL-Management Studio, open the Database-Explorer (left panel), put the cursor over the STored Procedure you´re calling and RIGHT-BUTTON - MODIFY or RIGHT-BUTTON - EDIT.  See if the first parameter has a wrong comma at its end - if so, wipe it.

Comment: And, if you change the Substring function to MID, you must have something like:   mid(string, 1, string.length - 2)

Comment: I've edited the question to show you the stored procedure, If I run it as a normal query (start at SELECT and replace @ProductID with the string created by my substring statement) it returns all the information I need about the products I need it to. The only problem was that it wasn't working until I added the number 3 to the end of the procedure name.